# C. Conclusion of the rounded double

Tags: c++, double

How to remove rounded to the 2nd sign double? I found only option with in C++:

```
cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<x[i]<<endl;
```

But in that case it isn't clear how to make that that in C would be as:

```
printf("%.7hi"x[i]);
printf("    ");
```

That is, without transition to the next line and only 7 symbols.

Comment: Sorry for the edit. However, what do you mean?

Comment: What type is `x[i]`?

Comment: Subtract 5 from the next digit, e.g. for 2.446 to be printed with %.2f as 2.44, subtract 0.005. And 2.441 - 0.005 = 2.436, which will be rounded up to 2.44 when printed.

Comment: `printf("%.2f", (double) x[i]);`

Comment: @chux, that will round.

Comment: @Paul OgilvieYes it will round.  That is how I understand OP's question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, the effect of the `precision` property of an output stream depends on the stream's setting of the `floatfield` format flag.  Your C++ example sets that flag to `fixed`, which seems to correspond to the `%f` field descriptor in `printf()`.  I say "seems to" because I'm having trouble finding any documentation that requires exact correspondence, but I would anticipate that in practice they do correspond exactly.

In a C `printf()` format, the precision is a property of each output field.  It is expressed in the field descriptor between a decimal point and the conversion specifier (`f` here), possibly with a length modifier between.  Supposing that `x` is an array of either `double` or `float`, the C analog of your C++ statement is therefore either

```
printf("%.2f\n", x[i]);
```

or

```
fprintf(stdout, "%.2f\n", x[i]);
```

(these are equivalent).  These differ from the C++, however, in that the floating-point format and precision are not retained as persistent properties of `stdout`.